# Drush on an already existing project

Tags: drush

First, I apologise for this question, it'll probably look very simple to a lot of you, but I am quite new at this and can't seem to figure it out.

I am working on a project that requires that I import a lot of data from a wordpress site. For that I want to use wordpress migrate. This module recommends me to use drush to transfer the data.

After having had quite a lot of problem installing it (thank you windows) I finally managed it. Now I'd like to use drush on one of the projects that's in my wamp\www file.

How do I do that? I've been looking but can't find the solution

I tried the commands from this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1958170
but it says : 
"Command variable-set needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
Command variable- set requires Drupal core versu=ion 6 or 7 to run."

I am working with drush 7 and I am hoping to use it on a drupal 7-*...

Please help!!!!!

==== EDIT ====

Once I'm in the right place I no longer get the "needs a higher bootstrap level".

After reading a few things to sort out my problem (and probably messing things up) it came back, even if I am inside the sites folder.

I can download new modules but cannot enable them
I cannot activate the migrate module and commands

and I don't see the PDO drivers listed when I do drush php-eval "phpinfo();"

[image: cmd printscreen]

What's wrong with drush ?

Answer (score 1):

The "needs a higher bootstrap level" error means that you're not in the right directory to call drush.

Where's your drupal source directory ? `cd` to that directory , and try your drush command again...

Comment: my drupal project is in c:\wamp\www\projectname

Comment: cd there and try your drush command.

Comment: You could also try to cd in the the sites folder c:\wamp\www\projectname\sites\[yoursitename or default] and run drush from there

Comment: hmm what am I missing...

now it says :"not able to start (bootstrap) the drupal database"

Comment: Have a look at this thread : https://www.drupal.org/node/1393232 . Are your PDO drivers listed when you do `drush php-eval "phpinfo();"` ?

Comment: nope can't see them :/

Comment: And yet your drupal is working ? Search on how to enable PDO mysql support on your wamp/windows setup. This may be  a good starting point http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: Yeah my site is working fine. Not sure Drush is really making my life easier hehe.  I'll look into that what you suggest, thx

Comment: Once it works properly drush will make your life way easier. 
Likely your drush and your drupal are looking at different php.ini files. 
That's the first thing to check.

Comment: I created an alias for my drupal site, and I dont have the "cannot connect to the database". Nowit's only an issue of higher bootstrap level to run. Which is weird because the root is C:\wamp\www\lastlsn\sites...

Comment: how odd!! seems like drupal is using the php.ini from c:\wamp\www\bin\apache\apache***\bin
And drush the php.ini from 
C:\wamp\www\bin\php\php***\

Comment: Yup. get drush to use the same as drupal. And you should be set.

Comment: been trying to do that following this http://www.drush.org/en/master/configure/ but no chance it says to clear the cash, which I do and the same message comes all the time

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows based drupal configurations. But I'd say a QAD way to tackle this would be to copy over the contents of your  c:\wamp\www\bin\apache\apache***\bin\php.ini onto your C:\wamp\www\bin\php\php***\php.ini . The cleaner approach would be to find out why it's getting the php.ini from bin\php\php*** and not bin\apache\apache*** (PATH ? conf file somewhere ? .... )

Comment: @rtome Hiya, just to let you know that it's working now. I unstalled it and reinstalled and now it works!!!!! such a relief. I even saw all my modules ;)
Thanks for your time!